# Work done in lifting chain with nonuniform linear density

Tags: work

I am teaching calculus, and a natural-seeming problem type just occured to me.  It would go something like:  a 2m chain hangs from the top of a building.  Its density at a point h meters from the edge of the roof is 20-5h kg/m.  Find the work done in lifting the chain to the roof.

I just looked through the problems in the four calculus books I have handy, and found only examples with constant density.  On the other hand, they all have plenty of problems about pumping water from funny-shaped tanks.  These seem to me to be harder problems since you have to compute a cross-sectional area to determine the mass of a slice.

My question is, is there a reason why these books are avoiding the chain with nonlinear density problem above?  I worry that some physical assumption holds in the constant density case that doesn't hold in the nonconstant density case, like considering the tension or something, that makes it an unreasonable scenario.

Comment: The purpose of these exercises is to apply calculus to the real world; while everyone has filled a bottle with water, I doubt many have encountered a chain with non-uniform density. It seems a nice problem though.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the variable-density case isn't a common exercise because a non-uniform chain/rope isn't very common! But the definition of work,
$$
W=\int F(x)\,dx=\int g\mu(x)\,dx
$$
will work just fine here for the non-uniform chain.

As an aside, my calculus textbook, Thomas' *Calculus* (10th edition), covers non-constant forces of the form $F(x)=a-bx$. A non-linear problem won't be much different than this, from a calculus perspective.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a pretty straightforward problem, and there is no reason why you couldn't solve it with standard calculus methods. Go ahead and create your problem (and the solution). There's nothing tricky here.